# View multiple image using bootstrap modal in laravel 5.0

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I'm having trouble for almost 3 days  now with the code I have .I'm hoping that somebody could help me give any idea or right solution here.
what i want is upon clicking the view info button, it should display all the images in the modal but in my code, only one image has been displayed.In my javascipt code, i dont have any more idea how to loop
inside the script even if i've tried few ways.

Transaction

```
tran_id | title

1       | allownce

2       | food

3       | tuition fee
```

Database table 2

Image

```
image_id | tran_id | image_title

1        | 1       | receipt.png

2        | 1       | |receipt2.png

3        | 1       | receipt3.png

4        | 1       | receipt4.png

5        | 2       | receipt.png

6        | 2       | receipt2.png

7        | 2       | receipt3.png

8        | 3       | receipt.png

9        | 3       | receipt2.png
```

[This is the modal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8LYp.png)

controller

```
public function index()
{

    $trans = Transaction::with('listImage')->get();

    return view('pages.test',compact('trans'));
}
```

Relationship

```
public function listImage(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Image','tran_id','tran_id');
}
```

Table list

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>title Name</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($trans as $tran)
        <tr>
           <td>{!! $tran->title !!}</td>
           <td><a class="btn" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="{!! $tran->title !!}" @foreach($tran['listImage'] as $image) data-image="../Transaction/{!! $image->tran_file !!}" @endforeach data-target="#image-gallery"><button>View Info</button></a></td>  
        </tr>   
       @endforeach
    </table>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadGallery(true, 'a.btn');
    function loadGallery(setIDs, setClickAttr){
        var current_image,
        selector,
        counter = 0;
        function updateGallery(selector) {
            var $sel = selector;
            var thisImage = $(this).data('image');
            current_image = $sel.data('image-id');
            $('#image-gallery-caption').text($sel.data('caption'));
            $('#image-gallery-title').text($sel.data('title'));
            $('#image-gallery-image').attr('src', $sel.data('image'));
            disableButtons(counter, $sel.data('image-id'));
        }

        if(setIDs == true){
            $('[data-image-id]').each(function(){
                counter++;
                $(this).attr('data-image-id',counter);
            });
        }
        $(setClickAttr).on('click',function(){
            updateGallery($(this));
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

[here the modal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQV5D.png)

Comment: The first part of your post that is not format is unclear to me. Could you provide the output of `var_dump($trans)`? Also, why do you need javascript, can't you just use the `data-toggle` attribute for your modal in combination with bootstrap `Carousel`?

Comment: I'd tried not using javascript but the result is always the last row of the foreach loop which is the data is directly from database.Now when i use javascript, it works fine but the issue now is if i've multiple images to be displayed or retrieve through modal the result is only one is being displayed.